# Contact Form 7 - Mail Tag Styling

Tags: contact-form-7

First post here but i've been struggling with something for a while. I'm creating a form in Contact Form 7, and tweaking the Mail reply using the mail tags. I'm using several sections of checkbox items, but when they're relayed back via the email, the checked box text displays as follows: 
red, green, yellow, blue etc

However, i'd like them to display as:

- red
- green
- yello
- blue

The checkboxes I want to include on my form are longer sentences so they just display as a big block of sentences rather than a list when sent in an email to the form host/person filling in the form.

I can't find a way to get into the mail tag [checkbox] to style that item in particular, despite being able to style the email generated in general (bold text, coloured text etc). I've tried several (probably quite amateur) things, but nothing is working.

This page on my site has an example of what i'm talking about: http://www.adgreen-apa.net/social-contact/send-us-your-thoughts

Any help appreciated!

Comment: p.s. Clyde came close to answering it on this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13351259/contact-form-7-wordpress-style-the-hml-mail-template/46325312?noredirect=1#comment79613292_46325312

Comment: The closest i've got is using inline css like this: <p style="color:blue;margin-left:30px;">[checkbox-12]</p> which works, however if i try to amend the style to say display:block or display:list-item, it has no effect, as it doesn't seem to control the individual returned answers, only the item as a whole.